# r how to use paste to create a variable like {\test}

Tags: r

I want to create an variable, say `temp`, that looks like `{\test}`

When I use paste like this

```
  temp <- paste('{\', "test", "}", sep ="")
```

R thinks its not correct because it thinks the \ is a regex. However,

```
temp <-  paste('{\\', "test", "}", sep ="")
```

temp looks like this.

```
{\\test}
```

Comment: Try to print it with `cat(paste('{\\', "test", "}", sep =""))`. There is only one `'\'`. Or maybe with a newline at the end, `cat(paste('{\\', "test", "}", sep =""), "\n")`.

Comment: {\\test} is indeed {\test}. It's just  that R sees ``\`` as an escape character---and is a special character. If you want to see the exact representation of a string (for outside R world), check it with `cat("{\\test}", "\n")`.

Comment: @Eyayaw Yes, that's much simpler than my comment. Then run `cat("{\test}", "\n")`. The escape sequence `"\t"` kicks in and a horizontal tab is printed.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, Read the help file for more info:   `?Quotes`

Comment: I have edited the question to emphasis that I want to store the output of paste in a variable. cat won't let you do that, I think.

Comment: you can capture output of cat : capture.output(cat("\\")). cat stores \\ but shows \

Comment: did you take a look at this answer. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/how-to-build-the-following-the-string-in-r